# Django: Auto Generate a CharField using data from another CharField

Tags: python, django

I have two charfields, `name` and `url`. `name` is something like "My group", and I want the `url` field to be automatically derived from the `name` entry. So it would be something like "my_group".

This is how I tried to accomplish this, but it doesn't work.

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
url = models.CharField(max_length=140, default=name.replace (" ", "_"))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) your model's [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method and set the `url` field value there:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = self.name.replace(' ', '_').lower()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

See also:

- [Django Model Field Default Based Off Another Field in Same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model)

Also note that, having a field that is just a logical transformation of another field of the model is basically a sign that you are doing things incorrectly. Consider having a [`property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/glossary/#term-property) or a custom method (`get_url()`, for example) on a model instead.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You could either turn `url` into a [@property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) of your Model:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=140)

@property
def url(self):
    return self.name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
```

**2)** Or [override the the model's save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
url = models.CharField(max_length=140)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url = self.name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
    super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The difference between the two is that in **1** the `url` is not saved to the database, while in **2** it is. Implement whichever fits your situation better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django admin, you could just slugify it.

In your model you would have:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
slug = models.CharField()
```

Then in admin.py:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields for more