# Accessing ForeignKey instance fields in Django model

Tags: python, database, django, relational-database

I'm having trouble visualizing a database query I want to run in Django. Let's say I have a couple simple models defined:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Topping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey('pizza')
    # Get the name of pizza here
```

EDIT: I need to access the name in another field, not in an instance method. Is this possible?

I currently don't know how to do this. I've tried

```
pizza.name
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's why I mentioned the `instance` requirement, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get a related field value, you need a model instance, `Topping` class instance in your case. For example, you can have a custom method defined on the `Topping` class:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey('pizza')

    def get_pizza_name(self):
        return self.pizza.name
```

`self` here refers to a class instance.

Example usage:

```
topping = Topping.objects.get(pk=1)
print topping.get_pizza_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
topping = Topping.objects.get(pk=1)
print(topping.pizza.name)
```