# Django Forms - Set username field equal to email field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've got a Django Model Form and I am trying to set the username field equal to the email field.

Here's my form

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username')
```

I am currently using some JavaScript to copy the new email value to the username hidden input before the user submits the form but I would like to do this server side.

I've tried to set it by doing the following `UserForm['username'] = email` before saving the form and got the following error `object does not support item assignment`.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use the answer provided or try some app that handles that for you. You may want to check https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth 2 lines in your settings.py and you got what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I did not test this, I think it would work.  If not check out overriding the save method which definitely works. [Django Model Field Default Based Off Another Field in Same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model)

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(default=email)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User
```

more info
[enter link description here](https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2020-01/email-as-username-django/)

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username')
        email = forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Email"})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = user.email
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```