# Model attribute based on another attribute

Tags: python, django, models

Is it possible to make one model attribute depends on another attribute? In my case there is a `has_translator` attribute in model `Job`. I want this attribute to be `True` if and only if the `translator` is not `Null`.

I was considering overriding a `save` method of class `Job` or creating a new method property `has_translator` which is probably not a best way.

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model) talking about overriding the `save` method but I'm not sure why is calling `super` for in this case so I'm not sure if I should use it.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='customer')
    translator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='freelancer',null=True)

    description = models.TextField()
    language_tuple = models.ForeignKey(LanguageTuple,related_name='language_tuple')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_translator = # If translator is not None/Null, then True else False
```

Comment: Do you really need a field stored in the db for this? Why not just a property on the model?

Comment: `super` method is called in-order to do the rest.. And note that `self.subject_init = self.subject_initials()` on the link should modifiy the self obj. That modified self is passed to the super method.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add it as a property, it doesn't make any sense to add it as a field since you could just filter based on the translator if you need it in a queryset, and for anything else that doesn't involve the database, just use the property

```
@property
def has_translator(self):
    return self.translator_id is not None
```

Comment: Just a quibble, it would be better to use `self.translator_id` here so that it doesn't trigger an unnecessary db query when there is a value.

Comment: This seems to work but I'm not sure whether then can I call this property in templates as an attributes. job.has_translator...

Comment: @Milano - Sure you can, pretty much exactly as you have written it there