# How can I set the field value in django admin based in another field's lookup?

Tags: django

I'd like to get the product price of the selected product and set to price in Order_line.

```
Theres are the models:

    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Product(models.Model):
        part_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Order(models.Model):
        customer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Order_line(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product  = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is overriding the **save()** method of **Order_line Model** like the following:

```
class Order_line(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product  = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.price is None:
                self.price = self.product.price
            super(Order_line, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Since the `self.price` value will always be equal with `self.product.price` .

More info about this in the documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

I hope this will help you.

**UPDATE**

**Now as per your comment,** you now realized that the above original arrangment (yours) can cause little complications if the product price is saved in more tables at the same time. You are right. From this approach what you asked in your question, the product price should only be edited in the **Product table** (not in Order_line table). However, this design (saving the same value in two tables) is relatively redundant since in your code **you can always get the product price from Product table** (Product Model), so my advise would be not to save the product price in two tables. Only in one, and you will always be able to edit the price in one place, and have the product price **from Product Model** if needed in your codes anywhere. With a few lines of codes like this:

```
def get_price(part_number):

    product_part_number = part_number
    obj = Product.objects.get(part_number=product_part_number)
    product_part_price = getattr(obj, price)
    # do whatever you want with this value, save or display anywhere
    return product_part_price
```

**However,** if you have a specific reason to save the product price in another table too, for example with every order, then the above solution is an optimal solution, that the product price is always based on the product price from the Product table. And the function could be extended and modified

**And there can be infinite number of question about how is it better to store these kind of data** when you start to build your project with products. You will have not one but more product prices for example. You will have base_product_price, special_product_price, wholesale_product_price and so on... where to save them and if it was a good idea to link one table field to another is **beyond the scope of the original question**.

Comment: Great! Very simple solution and just saves the price. What is If I would like to get the price before saving it, so the user can change the price while editing/adding the current record?

Comment: @Jorge - according to the above code, this table always saves the record (the price) what is at the moment saved in the product table. It just always copies that from the product table. That is what you asked for in your question. There can be many many other versions and design of the data flow. With this version of structure, at creation of order, when saving it, the price of the product always taken and saved from the product table.

Comment: @Jorge - I updated my answer for you regarding your question.