# How to convert a models.IntegerField() to an integer?

Tags: django, model

i try to assign a default value to an attribute of my table. This value is the value of another attribute.
Here is an excerpt

```
nombre_etudiant = models.IntergeField()
place_disponible =models.IntegerField(default=int(nombre_etudiant))
```

I tried with to_pythyon(), we told me : 'to_python' is not defined
How to do !?

Comment: You can not do that, since you here work at the "class" level.

Comment: Okay. I understood

Comment: there are some ways to copy a field into another field before saving, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4380879/67579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add an attribute initialization inside `__init__` method.

The right way to do this will be

```
class Foo(models):
    nombre_etudiant = models.IntergeField()
    place_disponible =models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.place_disponible is None:
            self.place_disponible = self.nombre_etudiant
```

Answer (score 1):

You need override the save() method of the model class.

```
class MyModel(models):
   nombre_etudiant = models.IntergeField()
   place_disponible =models.IntegerField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.place_disponible:
           self.place_disponible = int(nombre_etudiant)
           super(Subject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```