# How to convert a models.IntegerField() instance to int?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on Django 4.0.2 in python 3.10.2

I've read [How to convert a models.IntegerField() to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202798/how-to-convert-a-models-integerfield-to-an-integer)(the poster actually need copy-constructor function).And I've searched for Google.

But it doesn't help.

what I want to do is:

```
#In app/models.py

class Foo:
    a1 = models.IntergeField()
    a2 = models.IntergeField()
    #....
    #many else
    b1 = convertToInt(a1) * 3 + convertToInt(a2) *4 + convertToInt(a7) #calc by needing
    b2 = convertToInt(a2) * 2 + convertToInt(a3) + convertToInt(a5) #calc by needing
    #....
    #many else
    #b(b is price actually) will be used in somewhere else.Its type need be int for programmer-friendly using
```

any advice?

P.S. English is not my first language.Please forgive my syntax mistakes.

### Edit 1:

if just `a1 * 3`, I will receive

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntegerField' and 'int'
```

And I'd like to explain why the solution in the above attached link is not work

the first answer use:

```
class Foo(models):
    nombre_etudiant = models.IntergeField()
    place_disponible =models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.place_disponible is None:
            self.place_disponible = self.nombre_etudiant
```

which I still can't mutiply the num by n. The code just do copying.I still can't get the value in `int` type.

the 2nd solution

```
class MyModel(models):
   nombre_etudiant = models.IntergeField()
   place_disponible =models.IntegerField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.place_disponible:
           self.place_disponible = int(nombre_etudiant)
           super(Subject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`self.place_disponible = int(nombre_etudiant)` this will catch excepetion like `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'IntegerField'`

Comment: Using just `a1 * 3 + a2 * 4 ...` does not work?

Comment: The answer you linked seems like it should achieve what you need. What was the problem utilizing it? Another thing, maybe you can look into using `@property` for this if you don't store `b1`, `b2` and other derived attributes.

Comment: @JonnathanCarrasco  hello, I add some more info.check it out please. thx!

Comment: @vinkomlacic hello, I add some more info.check it out please. thx!

Comment: In your edits, shouldn't it be `self.place_disponible = int(self.nombre_etudiant)`? Another important question: is this price required to be stored in the DB? If not, there is a very easy solution.

Comment: @vinkomlacic 1.yes I actually used self.nombre_etudiant though the solution use nombre_etudiant 2. No, there is no need to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated in the comments that you don't need to store the derived attributes, I propose the following solution. Here the attributes are calculated every time and you can use them as you would use `a1` and `a2` attributes.

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    a1 = models.IntegerField()
    a2 = models.IntegerField()
 
    @property
    def b1(self):
        return self.a1*3 + self.a2*4  # + ...

    @property
    def b2(self):
        return self.a2*3 + self.a3  # + ...
```

Comment: thanks very much. Thanks for you time and your exactly good solution