# Django: How to Auto-Populate a field with another two field's value in same model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I and want to auto-populate the tags field in my Django model with the value of the category & subcategory. I tried to find solutions but most of the answers leads to (auto-populate from another model). But I want to auto-populate it with value of two or more fields in the same model.

```
from django.db import models
from .category import cat, sub_cat

# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model):

    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=cat(), default="")
    subcategory = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=sub_cat(), default="")
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="shop/images", default="")
    tags =
```

Answer (score 3):

Override the default save method:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    fields here     

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tags = self.category + '' + self.subcategory
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

when calling .save() it will automatically take category and subcategory and concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

This link should have the information you're looking for:

[Django Model Field Default Based Off Another Field in Same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model)

In your case I think you'd want to create a function that creates your tags based on other fields and then override the save function to set tags.

```
def your_function(self):
    return self.category + ', ' self.subcategory


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.tags:
        self.tags= self.your_function()
    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```