# Using other models's attribute as default

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Below are some parts of my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from places.fields import PlacesField

class DonorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dropoff_location = PlacesField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

```
from django.db import models
from register.models import DonorProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ResourcePost(models.Model):
    donor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    dropoff_location = PlacesField(blank=True, null=True, default=###)
    ...
```

My question is on the ### part.
I want to have the value of `DonorProfile`'s `dropoff_location` be the default value of `ResourcePost`'s `dropoff_location`.

So basically put something like

```
default=DonorProfile.objects.get(donorprofile_id).dropoff_location)
```

as the default value.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Model Field Default Based Off Another Field in Same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the model's `save` method, not as a default attribute. So try the following:

```py
def save(*args, **kwargs):
    if not self.dropoff_location:
        self.dropoff_location = self.donor.dropoff_location
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: so I guess setting default beforehand is not possible?

Comment: Yes i'm afraid its not. Just work arounds you can employ.