# Insert duplicate column value in Django

Tags: python, django

*Is there any way how can I duplicate value to another column,the value should be the same whenever I upload data to column 1 for example. I have `3000` in column 1, the value of column 2 should automatically write `3000`, it is possible to trick in models? or When Inserting query instead using default?* Thanks in advance!.

*Current output*

```
Column 1         Column 2
 5000              5000
 3650              5000
 2000              5000
```

*Expected output*

```
Column 1         Column 2
 5000              5000
 3650              3650
 2000              2000
```

*models.py*

```
class Person(models.Model):
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    amount_paid = models.CharField(max_length=60,default='5000', null=True)
```

Comment: refer this ans : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381252/1079086

Comment: If the columns should be on sync why the 2nd column?

Comment: @Klaus D. Yes, second column should be the same in first column,eg `amount _paid` should the same value in `amount`

Comment: @MarieLoise : As mentioned in link i have shared. you can overwrite your save method which will take information from first column and assign it to second column

Comment: But why do you need a second column? You could just use the first one. It has the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override the save method:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    amount_paid = models.CharField(max_length=60,default='5000', null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.amount_paid = self.amount
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But there is no need to store duplicate values unless you need it, you can simply add a boolean field, `is_paid` and set it True as default.

Also there is a certain pitfall of the given solution, that is if you change the amount, amount_paid will be changed automatically. If you want to update amount_paid if the Person instance is created, then you can add a if else logic:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:  # instance not created yet
       self.amount_paid = self.amount
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Alternativly, you can use Django Queryset to update bulk amount of `amount_paid`. For example:

```
from django.db.models import F
Person.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3]).update(amount_paid=F('amount'))
```