# Setting Djando field default value based on another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating a Django model where:

1. expirationTimeStamp field's default value is based on creationTimeStamp
2. isLive boolean field value is based on expirationTimeStamp

I have written the following functions **expirationTimeCalculation** and **postLiveStatus** and assigned them as default values to the fields but I am getting error. I have also tried to assign to respective fields through property(function) yet I am still getting error.

One of the functionality that I need to implement is that user can send custom expirationTimeStamp as well that would override default value, therefore, I believe property(function) assignment is not ideal for expirationTimeStamp field.

Is there any other way that I can go about to set the expirationTimeStamp field value based on creationTimeStamp field?

Any feedback is appreciated!

```
 class Posts(models.Model):
    
    def expirationTimeCalculation(self):
        EXPIRATION_DURATION = 86400 #time in seconds
        expirationTime = self.creationTimestamp + timedelta(seconds = EXPIRATION_DURATION)
        return expirationTime

    def postLiveStatus(self):
        return (self.expirationTimestamp > timezone.now)


    message = models.TextField() 
    creationTimestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    expirationTimestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=expirationTimeCalculation)
    isLive = models.BooleanField(default=postLiveStatus)
```

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar answered question. I am attaching the official documentation as well as the link to the answered question.

> Models certainly do have a "self"! It's just that you're trying to define an attribute of a model class as being dependent upon a model instance; that's not possible, as the instance does not (and cannot) exist before your define the class and its attributes.
>
> To get the effect you want, **override the save()** method of the model class. Make any changes you want to the instance necessary, then call the superclass's method to do the actual saving. Here's a quick example.
>
> ```
> def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>     if not self.subject_init:
>         self.subject_init = self.subject_initials()
>     super(Subject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
> ```

[Model Overriding Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods)

[Django Model Field Default Based Off Another Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381252/8401179)

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer helped me save so much time

Answer (score 0):

I needed field `end_day` to default to the last day of month in serializer. So I did this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    year = serializers.IntegerField()
    month = serializers.IntegerField()
    end_day = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=None)
    def end_day_value(self):
        return self.validated_data['end_day'] or \
               (datetime(year=self.validated_data['year'], month=self.validated_data['month'])+relativedelta(months=1)-relativedelta(days=1)).day
```

So when I need `end_day` or its default value I just call `end_day_value` method.