# If/when statement in django models to create another model field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a model field that is a result of another model field. I am unable to articulate this properly, but I will try anyway.

I have employees who include everyone in the office, then I have a role for them too.
All the staff are Engineers, and a few of the Engineers are also Managers. so when creating an Employee, I have to select if they are just an Engineer or a Manager.

if  the role is a Manager, then I want to create a model field as

```
manager = models.Charfield(???????????)

from django.db import models

class Roles(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=22)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

class Engineers(models.Model):

   region = (
      ('SS', 'South-South'), ('SW', 'South-West'), ('SE', 'South-East'),
      ('NE', 'North-East'), ('NW', 'North-West'), ('NC', 'North-Central'),
       )

   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
   position = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, max_length=20)
   workarea = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=region)
   manager = models.(if role selected = Manager), then the Employee name should be here



   def __str__(self):
       return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
```

I'd appreciate any help or redirection to any resources that can help or any different way of doing this.

the manager field should be a dropdown of the list of existing employees with the Manager status.

Comment: You can use [Django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/). Using the `post_save` method, when Roles will be created you can check the role and change the Engineers table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Model Field Default Based Off Another Field in Same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model)

Comment: @sytech Your suggestion looks like what could solve my issues, but since I'm a newbie, I'm actually finding it difficult to apply it,  can you help?