# Django - Default value based on another model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my existing django model

```py
class Account(models.Model):
    env = CharField(max_length=10)
```

now I need to add `period` field to my model based on the value of the `env` field in model. I can get the `period` value based on the `env` from following dict in my `settings` file

```
mydict = {
    'dev':1,
    'prd':2
}
```

How do I add my period field to model?

```py
period = Integerfield(default=setvalue from dict)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Model Field Default Based Off Another Field in Same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model)

Comment: but it does not add `period` field to the existing models, only after manually save the object again the field get updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom migration after running `makemigrations`, you open the migration file created and add a function like this

```py
from django.db import migrations

def set_default_value(apps, schema_editor):
    Account = apps.get_model("YOURAPPNAME", "Account")
    for account in Account.objects.all():
        if account.end == "dev":
            account.period = 1
        elif ...
            ...
        account.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (...),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(...),
        migrations.RunPython(
            set_default_value,
        ),
    ]
```

More information about migrations data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/)

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings

class Account(models.Model):
    env = CharField(max_length=10)
    period = Integerfield(blank=True)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Account)
def account_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.period is None:
        env = instance.env.lower()
        instance.period = settings.mydict.get(env)
```

I hope that works out for your problem.